# Register dll on Windows 7 in C#

Tags: c#, dll, windows-7, registry

How can I register my written dll's on Windows 7?

I found this code fragment but it seems to not work in Windows 7:

```
public static void registerDLL(string dllPath) 
{
  try {
    //'/s' : indicates regsvr32.exe to run silently.
    string fileinfo = "/s" + " " + "\"" + dllPath + "\"";

    Process reg = new Process();
    reg.StartInfo.FileName = "regsvr32.exe";
    reg.StartInfo.Arguments = fileinfo;
    reg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    reg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    reg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    reg.Start();
    reg.WaitForExit();
    reg.Close();
    }
catch(Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this under an Administrator account?

Comment: Yes. But I thought there comes an dialog to give the process the rights ?!

Comment: you have to elevate the other process. Why don't you do this properly with an installer instead of this very hacky approach.

Comment: Indeed.  This has also more than 50% odds to not work properly on a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems to not work"? Please clarify.

Comment: @David: Yes, this would be better! Have you any ressources???

Comment: Use the install package tool that comes with VS

Comment: This code is working for me on Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

The tool "regsvr32.exe" can register native COM-Dll's only. If you want to register a DotNet COM object written in C#, then you have to use "regasm.exe" instead. To do it, you need to be elevated, because it writes to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in the registry.

Comment: Hi! Thank you. I have .net dll's and com dll's

Answer (score 0):

```
reg.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

This can be a dirty workaround. Learn about UAC, and you should find out the recommended approaches from Microsoft,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511445.aspx